# SQLite Left join tables after two queries

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm trying to perform a join between two tables as written below. I'm at a loss at what to look for and what to troubleshoot. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT PART_NUMBER, PART_DESCRIPTION, AVG(JOB_QUANTITY_SCHEDULED) FROM JOBS GROUP BY PART_NUMBER)
    left join
(SELECT ITEM, ITEM_COST,  COSTING_LOT_SIZE, FIXED_DAYS_SUPPLY FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTE)
    ON JOBS.PART_NUMBER == ITEM_ATTRIBUTE.ITEM
```

Am getting the error

> no such column: JOBS.PART_NUMBER:

was looking to get an output with these columns

> PART_NUMBER, PART_DESCRIPTION, AVG(JOB_QUANTITY_SCHEDULED, ITEM,
>   ITEM_COST,  COSTING_LOT_SIZE, FIXED_DAYS_SUPPLY

for all items on in the Jobs Query

Comment: Please show us the output that you are expecting to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to alias your subqueries like so:

```
select * from
(
  SELECT part_number, part_description, AVG(job_quantity_scheduled) 
  FROM JOBS 
  GROUP BY PART_NUMBER
) as itemjobs

left join

(
  SELECT ITEM, ITEM_COST, COSTING_LOT_SIZE, FIXED_DAYS_SUPPLY 
  FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTE
) as itemattr

on itemjobs.part_number = itemattr.item
```

Without the alias, SQLite is not able to figure out where to look for JOBS table. Giving each sub-query an alias will help SQLite perform field mapping correctly.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the clear structure. Helps me understand this for the future